# return only the latests row of a bug ID status

Tags: mysql, max

I need some help trying to find the right command to return only one rown per bug number. The following code is querying a bug history table and it returns all entries for the bug. But all I want is the latest value.

```
 select bughist.id,bughist.user_id,bughist.bug_id,bughist.field_name,
   case 
   when bughist.old_value = 10 then 'New'
   when bughist.old_value = 20 then 'Feedback' 

    when bughist.old_value = 40 then 'Confirmed' 
    when bughist.old_value = 50 then 'Assigned' 
    when bughist.old_value = 55 then 'Deferred' 
    when bughist.old_value = 60 then 'RFT' 
    when bughist.old_value = 80 then 'Resolved'
    when bughist.old_value = 90 then 'Released' 
    when bughist.old_value = 95 then 'Rejects' 
    Else NULL End as 'Old_value', 
    case when bughist.new_value = 10 then 'New'
    when bughist.new_value = 20 then 'Feedback'
    when bughist.new_value = 40 then 'Confirmed' 
    when bughist.new_value = 50 then 'Assigned' 
    when bughist.new_value = 55 then 'Deferred' 
    when bughist.new_value = 60 then 'RFT' 
    when bughist.new_value = 80 then 'Resolved'
    when bughist.new_value = 90 then 'Released' 
    when bughist.new_value = 95 then 'Rejects' 
    Else NULL End as 'New_value',
    bughist.type,from_unixtime(bughist.date_modified) as 'moddate' from bug_history_table bughist
    left join bugtracker.bug_table bug 
    on bughist.bug_id = bug.id 
    where field_name = 'status'  and bug.project_id in (23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31)
    group by bughist.date_modified
    order by bughist.bug_id, bughist.id
```

What comes out is

[image]

But I do not want all these rows.  As you can see from the hiughlighted one on the picture.  this is the last update made to that specific bug.  So what I want to show with this query is only the last updated row for each known bug id.  I have tried MAX and having but get no joy'

Comment: order by bughist.date_modified and limit the select query to 1. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/select.html

Comment: You haven't read the MySQL documentation, it seems. Go ahead and do that now.

Comment: I am new to Mysql  so I am learning as I go.   wont the limit just bring back the one row only when I want a lst entry for each of the bugs listed?

Comment: OT: I suggest you change your database structure and normalize it properly http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm These old_values belong in a table that you JOIN to your query. That gets rid of the ugly CASE